# Assigning permissions to Azure AD B2C application in Portal fails with "Data validation error"

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory

I have created a video to show you exactly what's happening: http://sendvid.com/urqpzeg2

I'm simply trying to give my application privileges to read directory data, and it fails with the following error:

> Failed to add application Windows Azure Active Directory's
>   permissions. Error detail: Unable to complete the request due to data
>   validation error.

I created the app via the Portal, and then added it to the Company Administrator role via Powershell. I couldn't assign permissions before or after giving the app the Company Administrator role.

I'm logged in as the Directory owner.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also could reproduce this issue. Based on the video, it seems you want to grant the app-permission to the b2c application. As a workaround, we can register a new normal application for the b2c tenant on the old Azure portal like figure below:
[image]

Then we can use this app to call the Azure AD graph REST and you can also see the required mission already be set in the new portal like figure below:
[image]

And for the original issue, I am also trying to report it internally.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer as it does answer the original question, but I am having another related issue. 

I've now successfully managed to create an application and assign permissions in the old portal. The problem I have now is that when I try to log in to B2C using this apps ID, I receive the following error: The provided application with ID '[application ID]' is not valid against this service. Please use an application created via the B2C portal and try again.

Comment: @gfyans the new app is a workaround for calling the Azure AD graph using the **client credential**, to authenticate with B2C tenant, you still need to use the old app.

Comment: So to confirm, I need 2 apps - 1 to log the user in (created in the new Portal), and 1 to allow the Graph to access directory data (created in the old portal)? OK, hopefully you guys get this sorted soon.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/ should be of some help in this scenario.